# timeit faster than it should be

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running a test with timeit and am not understanding what is going on.  I've been evaluating 2 raised to a power but every time it says it takes 0.02 ± 0.01 seconds. What am I doing wrong?

Example:

This will take 2.5 mins to execute:

```
2**10000000
```

This will return instantly with something like 0.01637562597170472:

```
timeit.Timer(stmt="2**10000000").timeit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
2**10000000
```

This doesn’t take 2.5 minutes to execute. It takes 2.5 minutes to convert to a decimal string, which is how integers are printed by default. Try `(2**10000000) % 10000000` or `len(hex(2**10000000))`.

Comment: There are much faster algorithms for binary-decimal conversion, but Python uses a simple one. You can find faster implementations of this operation and arbitrary-precision math in general in third-party libraries like [gmpy2](https://github.com/aleaxit/gmpy).

Comment: With a faster algorithm, this conversion takes under a second instead of 2.5 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Additional supplement of @Ryan, If you try `a = 2 ** 10000000`, it will return immediately. But then if you try `print(a)`, it takes such a long time to execute.

As @Ryan has said, this long time is cost by converting to decimal string. As `timeit.Timer(stmt="2**10000000").timeit()` won't print anything, it returns also immediately.